# Error : Property 'encryption Scheme' not valid in version 43.0

Tags: deployment, custom-field, ant

[image: what changes do i need to do?]

what i need to change here? how to over come this Error?
MY package.xml is 44.0

Answer (score 1):

If you are deploying to an instance that's still on v43.0 meaning on summer 18 then remove the line that has encryption scheme property.

Otherways you should be fine once your org is upgraded since the property got introduced in v44.0